# directory size from a virtual directory on a remote server

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the properties or just size of the directory that resides on a remote server, so the path must consist of 
IP/Virtual Directory/Data Repository

```
http://192.169.1.5/MyVirtualDir/MyData/
```

I'v tried it with curl and php.

```
    $remoteFile = "192.168.1.5/MyVirtualDir/MyData/";
$ch = curl_init($remoteFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //not
$data = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); if ($data === false) { echo 'cURL failed'; exit; }

$contentLength = 'unknown';
$status = 'unknown';
if (preg_match('/^HTTP\/1\.[01] (\d\d\d)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $status = (int)$matches[1];
}
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}

echo 'HTTP Status: ' . $status . "\n";
echo 'Content-Length: ' . $contentLength;


ERROR:scandir() [function.scandir]: connect() failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: What kind of server is that? A windows/samba network share? Or a HTTP server? You need to know that curl is for HTTP/FTP mostly. So you might just have thrown code on your problem that does something totally different. Why do you think it solves your issue?

Comment: You can't do this. You are not "allowed" to know "each" file in this directory... What if there were some files that you didn't have the permission to view them? How would they be calculated? - however, take a look at this note: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#94566